# Replace characters in url string between _ and .jpg

Tags: php, replace

I have this url in a string.

```
$string = 'http://www.mysite.com/category/subcategory/date/12345678901234b31af3215702298964_100x100.jpg';
```

I need to replace characters between `_` and `.jpg` and put `example` instead.

Comment: use regular expressions

Comment: how, can you give me example?

Comment: `preg_replace('/_(.*)\.jpg/','_example.jpg',$string);`?

Comment: s starting point: http://regexr.com?38gdq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
$string = preg_replace('/_(.*)\.jpg/','_example.jpg',$string);
```